# Batch for loop - next item in list

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am making a batch script and need to use a for loop to get the next item in a list.

Here's my code:

```
for %%a in (%itemList%) do (
    echo Current item is %%a, next item is %%a+1
)
```

inside of %itemList% i have:

```
cat dog mouse car boat
```

(note the trailing space in the variable, this is from me appending data to the variable elsewhere in the script)

Unfortunately this does not do what I want it to do. Instead, I want it to print something like this:

```
Current item is cat, next item is dog
Current item is dog, next item is mouse
Current item is mouse, next item is car
Current item is car, next item is boat
Current item is boat, next item is
```

(note no trailing space, as it reached the end of the list. spaces are delimiters)

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Here are three ways to do it:

```
@echo off
set "itemList=cat dog mouse car boat"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "prev="
set "curr="
echo %itemList%

:: --- first approach with saving previous item
for %%a in (%itemList%) do (

    if defined curr (
        set "prev=!curr!"
    )
    set curr=%%a

    if "!curr!" neq "!prev!" if defined prev (
        echo Current item is !prev!, next item is !curr!
    )
)

echo Current item is !prev!, next item is

:: ---- second aproach with using arrays and subroutine
echo ----------------------------------------
:::::  filling the array ::::::::::
set /a index=0
for %%a in (%itemList%) do (

    set "itemArray[!index!]=%%~a"
    set /a index=index+1
    set itemList.length=!index!
)
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


for /l %%l in (0;1;%itemList.length%) do (
    set /a nextItem=%%l+1
    call ::dispTwoEl itemArray %%l !nextItem!

)


:: ---- third aproach with using arrays and nested for
for /l %%l in (0;1;%itemList.length%) do (
    set /a nextItem=%%l+1
    for %%n in (!nextItem!) do echo Current item is !itemArray[%%l]!, next item is !itemArray[%%n]!

)
exit /b 0

:dispTwoEl
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion 

set "firstIndex=%~1"
set "secondIndex=%~2"
echo Current item is !itemArray[%1]!, next item is !itemArray[%2]!
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it. Of course, this is much cleaner if it is written as a PowerShell script and not hacked into cmd.exe form.

```
SET "itemlist=cat dog mouse car boat"
powershell /NoLogo /NoProfile /Command ^
    "$a = '%itemlist%'.Split(' ');" ^
    "for ($i = 0; $i -lt $a.Length; $i++)" ^
        "{ 'Current item is {0}, next item is {1}' -f @($($a[$i]), $($a[$i+1])) }"
```

=== as a .ps1 file

```
$itemlist = 'cat dog mouse car boat'
$a = '%itemlist%'.Split(' ')
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $a.Length; $i++)
    { 'Current item is {0}, next item is {1}' -f @($($a[$i]), $($a[$i+1])) }
```